# How do I use 'excludeGroups' in Gradle-License-Plugin without complete Group-id's?

Tags: gradle, groovy, licensing, gradle-plugin

Im using the csvRenderer to get myself a list of every dependency used in a project, but without my own dependencies.
I've got a lot of dependencies with group id's like `'com.dtb.invoke:...'`, `'com.dtb.extend:...'` and so on.

Of course I could take every little dependency I have and write the full GroupId, but there are bound to be more coming in the future, and `'com.dtb.'` is the only static component of all of them.

And there lies my problem: `'com.dtb.'` is not the whole GroupID. I would like to do something like `'com.dtb.*'` as you can do in java-imports, to exclude any dependency with a GroupId beginning with `'com.dtb'`.

This is where I stand right now:

```
void configureLicenseReport(Project project) {
        project.licenseReport {
            // Set output directory for the report data.
            // Defaults to ${project.buildDir}/reports/dependency-license.
            outputDir = "${project.buildDir}/licenses"

            // Don't include artifacts of project's own group into the report
            excludeOwnGroup = true

            excludeGroups = ['com.dtb.invoke']
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a way to use wildcards https://github.com/jk1/Gradle-License-Report/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/github/jk1/license/LicenseReportExtension.groovy#L97 maybe raise an issue, or better, send a pull request?